# How do Node.js SQL Server extensions compare in connection pooling?

Tags: t-sql, node.js, ado.net, sql-server-2008-r2, connection-pooling

I am just getting into Node, and looking at some options for connecting to SQL Server.  A lot of the demos I have seen are simple "here's how to connect with this query...".  However, I haven't found much on how connection pooling is managed.

[Tedious](http://pekim.github.com/tedious/) and [node-tds](http://cretz.github.com/node-tds/) are built on the the TDS protocol.  I read through the documentation for [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/tdspool.htm) and how it manages connection pooling.  Are these related?

I also found another extension, [T-SQL FTW](http://www.poconosystems.com/archives/sql-server-windows-extension-for-node-js-t-sql-ftw/) that was written in C# with a C++ wrapper that allows it to communicate with Node. Since it uses ADO .NET managed code, I'm wondering if this is a better option for stable connection pooling through Node, and if there are other solid options available with benchmarks and more elaborate documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection pooling is normally implemented as a wrapper around a connection provider (such as Tedious or node-tds). Pooling is a separate concern, and I'm not sure that it belongs in the connection provider.

I'd suggest that you pick the driver that you want to use, and then write a simple connection pooling solution for it. It's a fairly straightforward task.

[I'm the author of Tedious.]